# Best Pythonic way to convert a str containing list of comma separated u-strings to an actual list

Tags: python, string, list, csv

What is the best Pythonic way to convert:

```
"[u'absolute_path_to_file1', u'absolute_path_to_file2']"
```

Which is of type str, notice the space after each comma, to:

```
['absolute_path_to_file1','absolute_path_to_file1']
```

I ended up with bunch of strip() and split() which is not pretty at all.

To clarify: another program is writing a list of absolute paths to disk (as a value of a key in a section created by ConfigParser). I have the ability to either adapt the generating script and/or the script reading back the values.

I found similar question, however, the input was not a plain string.

Comment: You can use `eval` If you are 100% (and I mean 100%!) sure, that the string will never ever contain any malicious code

Comment: Oh amazing! Thank you both. @Matthias: I am 100% sure.